# Doubt about a geometric solution to Problem $10$ of the $2017$ AIME I contest

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-explanation

The following is Problem $10$ of the $2017$ AIME I contest

> Let $z_1=18+83i,~z_2=18+39i,$ and $z_3=78+99i,$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}.$ Let $z$ be the unique complex number with the properties that $\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}~\cdot~\frac{z-z_2}{z-z_3}$ is a real number and the imaginary part of $z$ is the greatest possible. Find the real part of $z$.

The AoPS Wiki Page has a beautiful geometric solution to the problem (linked [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2017_AIME_I_Problems/Problem_10)).

The solution is as follows:

> Instead of thinking of complex numbers as purely a real plus a
> constant times $i$, let’s graph them and hope that the geometric
> visualization adds insight to the problem.
>
> [image]
>
> Note that when we subtract two vectors, the geometric result is the
> line segment between the two endpoints of the vectors. Thus we can
> fill in $z_3 - z_1, z_2 - z_1, z-z_2 $ and $z-z_3$ as so;
>
> [image]
>
> $\angle Z_3Z_1Z_2$ looks similar to $\angle Z_3ZZ_2$, so let’s try to
> prove that they are congruent. We can show this in the following way.
>
> Let us write $\frac{z_3 - z_1}{z_2 - z_1}$ as some complex number with
> form $r_1 (\cos \theta_1 + i \sin \theta_1).$ Similarly, we can write
> $\frac{z-z_2}{z-z_3}$ as some $r_2 (\cos \theta_2 + i \sin \theta_2).$
>
> The product must be real, so we have that $r_1 r_2 (\cos \theta_1 + i\sin \theta_1) (\cos \theta_2 + i \sin \theta_2)$ is real. $r_1 r_2$
> is real by definition, so dividing the real number above by $r_1 r_2$
> will still yield a real number. (Note that we can see that $r_1 r_2\not= 0$ from the definitions of $z_1,$ $z_2,$ and $z_3$). Thus we
> have
>
> $$(\cos \theta_1 + i \sin \theta_1) (\cos \theta_2 + i \sin \theta_2) = \cos \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 - \sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 + i(\cos \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 + \cos \theta_2 \sin \theta_1)$$
>
> is real. The imaginary part of this is $(\cos \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 + \cos \theta_2 \sin \theta_1),$ which we recognize as $\sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2).$ This is only $0$ when $\theta_1 + \theta_2 = k\pi$ for
> some integer $k$. Here $\theta_2$ represents the major angle $\angle Z_3ZZ_2$, and the angle we want is the minor angle, so we can rewrite
> the equation as $\theta_1 + 2\pi - \theta_2 = k\pi \implies \theta_1 - \theta_2 = (k-2)\pi$. We can see from the diagram that both $\theta_1$
> and $\theta_2$ are obtuse, so therefore $\theta_1 - \theta_2 = 0 \implies \boxed{\theta_1 = \theta_2}$.
>
> Now that we’ve proven this fact, we know that all four points lie on a
> circle, so let’s draw that in;
>
> [image]
>
> While $Z_1, Z_2, Z_3$ are fixed, $Z$ can be anywhere on the circle
> because those are the only values of $Z$ that satisfy the problem
> requirements. However, we want to find the real part of the $Z$ with
> the maximum imaginary part. This $Z$ would lie directly above the center
> of the circle, and thus the real part would be the same as the $x$-value
> of the center of the circle. So all we have to do is find this value
> and we’re done.
>
> Consider the perpendicular bisectors of $Z_1Z_2$ and $Z_2Z_3$. Since
> any chord can be perpendicularly bisected by a radius of a circle,
> these two lines both intersect at the center. Since $Z_1Z_2$ is
> vertical, the perpendicular bisector will be horizontal and pass
> through the midpoint of this line, which is ($18$, $61$). Therefore the
> equation for this line is $y=61$.  $Z_2Z_3$ is nice because it turns
> out the differences in the $x$ and $y$ values are both equal ($60$) which
> means that the slope of the line is $1$. The slope of the perpendicular
> bisector is, therefore, $-1$ and it passes through the midpoint, ($48$,$69$),
> so the equation of this line is $y=-x+117$. Finally, equating the two
> yields $$61=-x+117 \implies x = \boxed{56}$$
>
> ***Credits:** KingRavi, Anonymous*

I understand the entire solution, however, I am confused about how one initially decides the placement of $Z$ in the complex plane as we don't know its value. Since a lot of the intuition for the solution relies on the placement of $Z$, I would like to know what properties help to determine its position in the plane.

Comment: Probably a ton of experience in these types of problems…

Comment: I agree the placement of $z$ seems disingenuous in the first diagram, but in the algebraic arguments that follow, they prove the left implication of the general theorem that *four points $z,z_1,z_2,z_3$ lie on a circle if and only if  $$\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}\cdot\frac{z-z_2}{z-z_3}=\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}/\frac{z-z_3}{z-z_2}$$ is real*. The condition that the imaginary part of $z$ must be maximum then determines its placement in the diagram.